# scaling when sampling from multivariate gaussian

Tags: matlab, covariance, gaussian

I have a data matrix `A` (with dependencies between columns) of which I estimate the covariance matrix `S`. I now want to use this covariance matrix to simulate a new matrix `A_sim`. Since I assume that the underlying data generator of `A` was gaussian, I can simply sample from a gaussian specified by `S`. I do that in matlab as follows:

```
A_sim = randn(size(A))*chol(S);
```

However, the values in `A_sim` are way larger than in `A`. if I scale down `S` by a factor of 100, `A_sim` looks much better. I am now looking for a way to determine this scaling factor in a principled way. can anyone give advise or suggest literature that might be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has the function [mvnrnd](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/mvnrnd.html) which generates multivariate random variables for you.